# Reduction in sum of squares

Tags: regression, least-squares, r-squared

***"By fitting a model to the data, we 'explain' some of the variability; that is, we reduce the unexplained variability by some amount. The reduction in the unexplained variability is always the sum of the parameter estimates, each multiplied by the right-hand side of the normal equation that corresponds to that parameter."***  ~  Montgomery, D. C. (2008): Design and Analysis of Experiments, John Wiley.

Can you explain the **second line** either intuitively or mathematically.

Comment: The quotation clearly is not true.  Perhaps Montgomery meant to write that the reduction is *a function of* the sum *etc.*  As such, it appears he's merely trying to sketch in words the formula for $R^2.$

Comment: But it holds @whuber. He has used it several times in the book. Besides, in some other books too, they have used it to derive other quantities. The question is how do I explain that it holds.

Comment: It may help if you can provide one of the example used in the book.

Comment: @GreggH I don't know how to provide an example here. But here is the [link](http://wpage.unina.it/cafiero/books/design_and_analysis.pdf) for the pdf. You can refer to pg. 115.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what he's saying. The normal equation is:
$$X'X\beta=X'Y$$ 
Multiply both sides by $\beta'$ from left:
$$\beta'X'X\beta=\beta'X'Y$$
$$(X\beta)'X\beta=\beta'X'Y$$
Now look at the left hand side, it's a variance of $X\beta$, which is the explained part. Hence, multiplying the right hand side of normal equation by the parameters $\beta$ is equal to the explained variance, as your book says.

Note, that omitted $\frac 1 n$ in variance definition to keep equations easy to read, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: But my question is regarding the second line. How will you prove that statement mathematically?